# numpy narray assignment with using append

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, append, variable-assignment

numpy ndarray assignment

hi

is there better append using for this:
the output of this code is ok. but I want the better coding than it.

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[],[],[]])
b=np.array([1,2,3])

a=np.append(a,[[b[0]],[b[1]],[b[2]]] , axis=1)
```

result:

```
output=[[1],[2],[3]]
```

Comment: What's the goal here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the necessity for the array `a`
If you just want each element of `b` as an element of numpy array as elements of numpy array, you can do the following;

```
import numpy as np

b=np.array([1,2,3])

output = np.array([np.array([x]) for x in b])
```

Else as list of lists,

```
output = [[x] for x in b]
```

Comment: it is needed for a array such "a". because the "b" array is produced in a loop several time and I want to save its values at each step in format of array "a" .

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
In [189]: a=np.array([[],[],[]])
     ...: b=np.array([1,2,3])
     ...: 
     ...: a1=np.append(a,[[b[0]],[b[1]],[b[2]]] , axis=1)

In [190]: a.shape, b.shape, a1.shape
Out[190]: ((3, 0), (3,), (3, 1))

In [191]: a1
Out[191]: 
array([[1.],
       [2.],
       [3.]])
```

So to concatenate a (3,0) and (3,) you have to first change `b` into a (3,1):

```
In [192]: np.array([[b[0]],[b[1]],[b[2]]])
Out[192]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

But if that's your target, why even use `a` and `append`?  I suspect you are imitating a list `append` loop.  Don't!

It's easier to make a (3,1) `b` with a `newaxis` or `.reshape(3,1):

```
In [193]: b[:,None]
Out[193]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

`np.append` in a loop is a bad idea.  It's slow, making a whole new array with each append, with all the attendant copies.